# Get the List of views given by Linked servers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to retrieve all the views provided by a linked server. Is there a query or another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVER].[DATABASE].sys.views
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this stored procecure:

```
exec sp_tables_ex 'Your linked server connection'
```

on the master db